# sql query error no data displayed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select all data from 2 tables in an sql database. 
I searched the site and dried numerous ways but no sucess. 
One table has no data but the other is full of it. 
If i select each one individually i get good results, but if i use for instance:

```
select * from relatorio cross join temp
```

or

```
select * from relatorio r,temp t
```

or even:

```
select t.*, r.* from temp t inner join relatorio r on 1=1
```

The join works, but none of them shows data.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @HoneyBadger It sounds more like a `FULL JOIN`. Though I don't understand the point of just blindly perform a cartesian product between your tables

Comment: ^^^ Correct.  An INNER JOIN won't work because it will only return data that is included in BOTH tables.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Hi, i tried but still no result. i want to join the tables so that i can display the data in a report

Comment: @septaug you still need to clarify what you want. What happens when both tables have data?, how do you want to join them?

Comment: What is the relation between `relatorio` and `temp` tables? If there is no relation between these 2 tables, you need to use `CROSS JOIN` which yields Cartesian product.

Comment: @Venu Op already is using `CROSS JOIN`. The problem op is facing is that it returns 0 rows when one (or both) tables have no data

Comment: Do you want the cartesian product? It means that you want resultset equals to no of rows in first table multiply by number of rows in second table?

If yes, then use cross join. If you want to return matched or unmatched all rows, then use full outer join..see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three select statements in the questions are cross joins. 
A cross joins returns data only if both tables have at least one row.
It returns a cartesian product of both tables, meaning that every row in one table will be joined to every row in the other table.

> One table has no data but the other is full of it.

Since one of your tables is empty, it will return no results at all. You can think about it as multipling by 0.

Now you have two options: one is to use a full join and the other one is to use left join, in this case both will return the same results, since one table is empty:

```
select * 
from relatorio 
left join temp on <join condition> -- assuming temp is the empty table
```

or

```
select * 
from relatorio 
full join temp on <join condition> -- in this case, it doesn't matter what table is empty
```

Comment: Amazing, thats it. 
i used the second option.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return all matched and umatched rows, use Full Outer Join.The FULL OUTER JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1) and from the right table (table2).

The FULL OUTER JOIN keyword combines the result of both LEFT and RIGHT joins.

In SQL the FULL OUTER JOIN combines the results of both left and right outer joins and returns all (matched or unmatched) rows from the tables on both sides of the join clause.

**SQL FULL OUTER JOIN Syntax**:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

The SQL CROSS JOIN produces a result set which is the number of rows in the first table multiplied by the number of rows in the second table if no WHERE clause is used along with CROSS JOIN. This kind of result is called as Cartesian Product.

If WHERE clause is used with CROSS JOIN, it functions like an INNER JOIN.

An alternative way of achieving the same result is to use column names separated by commas after SELECT and mentioning the table names involved, after a FROM clause.

**CROSS JOIN SYNTAX**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
CROSS JOIN table2;
```